# MySQL Pivot data with fixed number of columns

Tags: mysql, pivot

The following is my `SELECT` statement which pivots my data nicely.

My Data Looks like this:

```
col_a | col_b | col_c | col_d   | Score
-------------------------------------
stuff | stuff | stuff | null    |  5
stuff | stuff | stuff | title_a |  3
stuff | stuff | stuff | title_x |  4
```

My current Pivot statement looks like this:

```
SELECT `col_a`, `col_b`, `col_c`,
    MAX(CASE `col_d` WHEN 'title_a' THEN `col_d` end) AS 'Title',
    MAX(CASE `col_d` WHEN 'title_a' THEN `score` end) AS 'Score'
    MAX(CASE `col_d` WHEN 'title_x' THEN `col_d` end) AS 'Title',
    MAX(CASE `col_d` WHEN 'title_x' THEN `score` end) AS 'Score'
    .....
```

This gives me the following results:

```
col_a | col_b | col_c | Title   | Score | Title   | Score
---------------------------------------------------------
stuff | stuff | stuff | title_a |   3   | title_x |   4
```

What I would like to do is check for more titles, however I only want to have four columns in the pivot. There will only ever be a maximum of 2 rows that require pivoting up to the record above. But `col_d` could contain any title.

For example I tried the following:

My Data now Looks like this:

```
col_a | col_b | col_c | col_d    | Score
-------------------------------------
stuff | stuff | stuff | null     |  5
stuff | stuff | stuff | title_a  |  3
stuff | stuff | stuff | title_x  |  4
stuff | stuff | stuff | null     |  5
stuff | stuff | stuff | title_a  |  3
stuff | stuff | stuff | title_bx |  4
```

My Pivot statement now looks like this:

```
SELECT `col_a`, `col_b`, `col_c`,
    MAX(CASE `col_d` WHEN 'title_a' THEN `col_d` end) AS 'Title',
    MAX(CASE `col_d` WHEN 'title_a' THEN `score` end) AS 'Score'
    MAX(CASE `col_d` WHEN 'title_x' THEN `col_d` end) AS 'Title',
    MAX(CASE `col_d` WHEN 'title_x' THEN `score` end) AS 'Score'
    MAX(CASE `col_d` WHEN 'title_bx' THEN `col_d` end) AS 'Second Title',
    MAX(CASE `col_d` WHEN 'title_bx' THEN `score` end) AS 'Score'
    .....
```

So as you can see I tried checking for another title, but that just gave me six columns, 2 of them null because in this case the two rows contained `title_a` and `title_bx`, so the middle two columns where filled with `null`.

The output I would like from the above data is:

```
col_a | col_b | col_c | Title   | Score | Title    | Score
---------------------------------------------------------
stuff | stuff | stuff | title_a |   3   | title_x  |   4
stuff | stuff | stuff | title_a |   3   | title_bx |   4
```

So my question is how can I check for multiple possible titles in `col_d`, and only have the 4 columns.

Comment: You want to check for multiple case of col_d but get the result as a table with 4 column? yeah. if this is the case so you can check your case with `MAX(CASE WHEN 'col_d' IN('title1','title2','title3','title4') THEN 'col_d' END) AS my_col`

Comment: Just the pivoted part needs to stay at four columns, but essentially yes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is kind of messy because MySQL doesn't have windowing functions and you want to include very specific values in the first set of `Title`/`Score` columns.  You can get the final result by using some [user variables](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/02/how-to-number-rows-in-mysql/) to create a row number for those rows where the `col_d` is not equal to `title_a`, then join that back to your table.

The syntax will be similar to the following:

```
select a.col_a, a.col_b, a.col_c,
  max(case when a.col_d = 'title_a' then a.col_d end) title1,
  max(case when a.col_d = 'title_a' then a.score end) score1,
  max(case when na.col_d <> 'title_a' then na.col_d end) title2,
  max(case when na.col_d <> 'title_a' then na.score end) score2
from yourtable a
left join
(
  -- need to generate a row number value for the col_d rows
  -- that aren't equal to title_a
  select n.col_a, n.col_b, n.col_c, n.col_d,
    n.score,
    @num:=@num+1 rownum
  from yourtable n
  cross join
  (
    select @num:=0
  ) d
  where n.col_d <> 'title_a'
  order by  n.col_a, n.col_b, n.col_c, n.col_d
) na
  on a.col_a = na.col_a
  and a.col_b = na.col_b
  and a.col_c = na.col_c
  -- in the event you have more than 2 row only return 2
  and na.rownum <= 2  
where a.col_d = 'title_a'  
group by a.col_a, a.col_b, a.col_c, na.rownum;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a30ef/2/0). This gets a result:

```
| COL_A | COL_B | COL_C |  TITLE1 | SCORE1 |   TITLE2 | SCORE2 |
|-------|-------|-------|---------|--------|----------|--------|
| stuff | stuff | stuff | title_a |      3 | title_bx |      4 |
| stuff | stuff | stuff | title_a |      3 |  title_x |      4 |
```

It was pointed out to me that if you will only ever have 2 other values, then you can simply JOIN the data and not use the user variable:

```
select distinct a.col_a, a.col_b, a.col_c,
  a.col_d title1,
  a.score score1,
  na.col_d title2,
  na.score score2
from yourtable a
left join
(
  select n.col_a, n.col_b, n.col_c, n.col_d,
    n.score
  from yourtable n
  where n.col_d <> 'title_a'
) na
  on a.col_a = na.col_a
  and a.col_b = na.col_b
  and a.col_c = na.col_c
where a.col_d = 'title_a';
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/46bbd/25/0). This gives the same result:

```
| COL_A | COL_B | COL_C |  TITLE1 | SCORE1 |   TITLE2 | SCORE2 |
|-------|-------|-------|---------|--------|----------|--------|
| stuff | stuff | stuff | title_a |      3 |  title_x |      4 |
| stuff | stuff | stuff | title_a |      3 | title_bx |      4 |
```

Depending on what you actually have for data in `col_a`, `col_b`, and `col_c` you might have to alter this but it should get you the result you need.

**Update:** Based on your comment that you will not know the values in the `col_d` column but you just need to split the data into two pivoted columns, the process gets complicated because MySQL doesn't have windowing functions.  This would be extremely easy if there was an `NTILE` function. The `NTILE` function  distributes the rows into a specific number of groups. In this case, your data is being split into 2 groups.

I've modified the code in [this blog](http://explainextended.com/2009/03/09/analytic-functions-ntile/) by SO User, [Quassnoi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/55159/quassnoi) to replicate the `NTILE` function using user variables. The variables are used to create 2 things, a row number (used during the pivoting) and the ntile value.

The code would be modified into:

```
select 
  x.col_a,
  x.col_b,
  x.col_c,
  max(case when x.splitgroup = 1 then x.col_d end) as Title1,
  max(case when x.splitgroup = 1 then x.Score end) as Score1,
  max(case when x.splitgroup = 2 then x.col_d end) as Title2,
  max(case when x.splitgroup = 2 then x.Score end) as Score2
from
(
  select src.col_a, src.col_b, src.col_c, src.col_d, src.score,
    src.splitGroup,
    @row:=case when @prev=src.splitGroup then @row else 0 end +1 rownum,
    @prev:=src.splitGroup
  from
  (
    -- mimic NTILE function by splitting the total count of rows
    -- over the number of columns we want (2)
    select d.col_a, d.col_b, d.col_c, d.col_d, d.score, 
      FLOOR((@r * @n) / cnt) + 1 AS splitGroup
    from
    (
      select a.col_a, a.col_b, a.col_c, a.col_d, a.score, grp.cnt
      from yourtable a
      inner join 
      (
        select col_a, col_b, col_c, count(*) as cnt
        from yourtable
        where col_d is not null
        group by col_a, col_b, col_c
      ) grp
        on a.col_a = grp.col_a
        and a.col_b = grp.col_b
        and a.col_c = grp.col_c
      where a.col_d is not null
      order by a.col_a, a.col_b, a.col_c
    ) d
    cross join
    (
      -- @n is equal to the number of new pivoted columns we want
      select @n:=2, @group1:='N', @group2:='N', @group3:='N'
    ) v
    WHERE 
      CASE 
        WHEN @group1 <> col_a AND @group2<> col_b AND @group3 <> col_c 
          THEN @r := -1 
          ELSE 0 END IS NOT NULL
      AND (@r := @r + 1) IS NOT NULL
  ) src
  cross join
  (
    -- these vars are used to get the row number once the data is split
    -- this will be needed for the aggregate/group by on the final select
    select @row:=0, @prev:=1
  ) v2
  order by src.splitGroup
) x
group by x.col_a, x.col_b, x.col_c, x.rowNum;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/804caa/17/0). This gives the result:

```
| COL_A | COL_B | COL_C |   TITLE1 | SCORE1 |   TITLE2 | SCORE2 |
|-------|-------|-------|----------|--------|----------|--------|
| stuff | stuff | stuff |  title_a |      3 | title_tt |      1 |
| stuff | stuff | stuff | title_bx |      0 | title_qq |      1 |
| stuff | stuff | stuff |  title_x |      4 |  title_a |      8 |
| stuff | stuff | stuff | title_yy |      3 |  title_h |      4 |
| stuff | stuff | stuff |  title_a |      2 |  title_o |      6 |
```

Comment: Wow, great answer and fiddles. There will be more than 2 values so user variables looks like the way to go. One small thing, and I realise that it probably wasn't very clear from my question - sorry, but the first 2 sets of `Title/Score` do not have to contain `title_a/score`. It just so happens I put that value first in both examples of data, It could be any two values. How would I change your current query to accommodate that?

Comment: @superphonic Can you edit/create a sql fiddle with some actual data and then post the link in a comment?  It's hard to give actual code without seeing valid data.

Comment: Absolutely... I have edited one of your fiddles and added some more data http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/804caa

Comment: @superphonic Ok with this new data, what do you expect the final result to look like?  If you have unknown values in the `col_d`, then do you just want the values split into 2 pivoted columns?

Comment: It needs to look like the results you initially had: `Title | Score | Title | Score`. So basically the two rows with the unknown/random values in `col_d` need to be pivoted up to the row with `null` in `col_d`

Comment: @superphonic Edited to include a version that doesn't hard-code the values.  The only thing that would still be a question would be using the values in `col_a`, `col_b` and `col_c` - you provided obviously fake data which could potentially skew the results

Comment: Brilliant!! Thank you for taking the time with the explanation and a working fiddle. Love learning something new!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correct. You could do something like this:

```
SELECT `col_a`, `col_b`, `col_c`,
MAX(CASE WHEN `col_d` IN('title_a','title_x','title_bx') THEN `col_d` end) AS 'Title',
MAX(CASE WHEN `col_d` IN('title_a','title_x','title_bx') THEN `score` end) AS 'Score'
...
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to produce what I need. I will update the question with the output of I am expecting.